# Distinct List(Of String) from two Lists

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, unique, distinct-values

I have two `List(Of String)` named `MethodCodes` and `MethodDescriptions`. I would like to create unique values.

E.g. I have these values in the lists...

`MethodCodes (45, 45, 46a, 46b, 47, 47)`

`MethodDescriptions (meth45, meth45, meth46, meth46, meth47, meth47)`

I need to reduce this Lists to this...

`MethodCodes (45, 46a, 46b, 47)`

`MethodDescriptions (meth45, meth46, meth46, meth47)`

Actually, the unique must be values in MethodCodes list, but the count of items must be the same in both lists.

Tomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values in these two list have an association then it would be a much better idea to *keep* them associated in an appropriate data structure such as a class.

A simple class like this would do it:

```
Private Class Method
    Public Property Code As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Sub New(code As String, description As String)
        Me.Code = code
        Me.Description = description
    End Sub
End Class
```

This allows you to add values like this:

```
Dim methods As New List(Of Method)
methods.Add(New Method("45", "meth45"))
methods.Add(New Method("45", "meth45"))
methods.Add(New Method("46a", "meth46"))
methods.Add(New Method("46b", "meth46"))
methods.Add(New Method("47", "meth47"))
methods.Add(New Method("47", "meth47"))
```

And then find the distinct Code values and the associated descriptions like this:

```
For Each distinctMethod In methods.Distinct.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Code).Select(Function(d) d.First()).ToList()
    Debug.WriteLine(distinctMethod.Code & "-" & distinctMethod.Description)
Next
```

Output:

```
45-meth45
46a-meth46
46b-meth46
47-meth47
```

Comment: Matt, this is very nice object oriented solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is more complicated than it needs to be, but since you have pairs of items I would probably combine them first (`Zip`) and find the distinct pairs, then split them up again.

```
Dim MethodCodes = New List(Of String)() From {"45", "45", "46a", "46b", "47", "47"}
Dim MethodDescriptions = New List(Of String)() From {"meth45", "meth45", "meth46", "meth46", "meth47", "meth47"}
' Combine the two lists, and find the distinct pairs
Dim zipped = MethodCodes.Zip(MethodDescriptions, Function(a, b) Tuple.Create(a, b)).Distinct().ToList()
' Split the values up again
MethodCodes = zipped.Select(Function(x) x.Item1).ToList()
MethodDescriptions = zipped.Select(Function(x) x.Item2).ToList()
```

If you had the same key with different values (e.g. 47 - meth47a, 47 - meth47b) then this would keep both, which may not be what you want ("the unique must be values in MethodCodes list").

Comment: This method assumes that the lists are in sync so can be paired as such.

Comment: That's what the question requests. You keep both `meth46`es because they're in the same place as two different values.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Agreed - maybe I read too much into the question, but I did work under that assumption.